# LINQ, creating unique collection of a collection

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have

```
class Vertex{
    Graph _graph;
    float x;
    float y;
    string key;
    //and some similar atributes
    public IEnumerable<Edge> Edges{
        get{
            return _graph.Edges.Where(s => s.Source == this);
        }
    }
}
class Edge{
    Graph _graph;
    Vertex source;
    Vertex target;
}
class Graph
{
    private VertexCollection _vertexCollection; // extends List<Vertex>
    private EdgeCollection _edgeCollection; //extends List<Edge>
    public IEnumerable<Vertex> Vertexes
    {
        get
        {
            return _vertexCollection;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<Edge> Edges
    {
        get
        {
            return _edgeCollection;
        }
    }
    public IDictionary<Edge, bool> DrawableEdges
    {
        get
        {
            //want to return my uniq dictionary
        }
    }
```

`Edges` and `Vertexes` are collected into lists

Some example:

```
A-->B // edge from vertex A to B
B-->C // edge from vertex B to C
C-->A // edge from vertex C to A
A-->C // edge from vertex A to C  -- this is two way edge
```

So I would like to make `IDictionary<Edge, bool>` which would hold edges (A-->B and B-->A would be like 1), and bool - if it is two way or no.

I need it because when I draw them now, it draws 2 arrows under one another. I would better make 1 arrow.

So I'm pretty stuck right here... May anybody help me a bit ?

Comment: Please show definition of the Edge and Vertex classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should implement the `IEquatable` interface for your `Edge` class:

```
public class Edge : IEquatable<Edge>
{
    ...

    public bool Equals(Edge other)
    {
        return (
            (other.Source == this.Source && other.Target == this.Target) ||
            (other.Target == this.Source && other.Source == this.Target));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Source.GetHashCode() ^ Target.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

and add your edges to a `HashSet<Edge>` collection. Then you can call its `Contains` method to check if it contains the edge or not.

EDIT: like Henk said, you can also implement a custom `IEqualityComparer` class:

```
public sealed class EdgeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Edge>
{
    public static EdgeComparer Default { get; private set; }

    static EdgeComparer()
    {
        Default = new EdgeComparer();
    }

    private EdgeComparer()
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(Edge x, Edge y)
    {
        return (
            (x.Source == y.Source && x.Target == y.Target) ||
            (x.Target == y.Source && x.Source == y.Target));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Edge edge)
    {
        return (edge.Source.GetHashCode() ^ edge.Target.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

and initialize your hashset with

```
_drawableEdges = new HashSet<Edge>(EdgeComparer.Default);
```

Comment: Or write a separate Comparer to perform the same logic. Also provide a symmetrical way to combine HashCodes

Comment: You might want to replace `==` with `Equals` to avoid the `NaN` issues. And of course the OP needs to implement `Equals`, `==`, `!=` and `GetHashCode()`

Comment: @CodeInChaos I think in this case `==` is good enough to check the equality.

Comment: @BalazsTihanyi no it isn't. `NaN`.Equals(NaN)==true` `(NaN==NaN)==false`

Comment: But this will make some troubles, since i use Dijkstras algorithm over this graph. From A to B you can go only one way, if i implement this, it will make possible also from B to A? isnt it?

Comment: @Wish For Dijkstra's you should use your original edge list. For drawing you can use an alternative `_drawableEdges` collection. Of course you will need to add the edges to both collections. If you don't want a separate collection you can also use the `Distinct` extension method on your original edges but I don't suggest it since the drawing would call it everytime.

Comment: @CodeInChaos But these are Vertex instances in a graph, so you can use reference equality comparison in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your Edge class has a constructor which takes 2 vertexes. See below for possible idea (I haven't compiled this, but hopefully you get the idea).

```
foreach(Edge edge in Edges)
{
    Edge edge2 = new Edge(edge.V2, edge.V1);
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(edge) && !dict.ContainsKey(edge2))
    {
        dict[edge] = false; // first time we've seen this edge, so put it in dictionary
    }
    else if (!dict.ContainsKey(edge) && dict.ContainsKey(edge2))
    {
        dict[edge2] = true; // a bidirectional edge
    }
}
```

Comment: ye, basicley i needed just idea